# Restlet + Google App Engine Issue:Unable to find a converter for this object

Tags: json, google-app-engine, jackson, restlet

I am trying to use Restlet on Google App Engine.
I was able to successfully use it when I was dealing with Strings.
But I am not able to make it work with Java objects.
As per Restlet documentation, it should work automatically (JSON conversion)

I am following the tutorial at 
[Restlet tutorial](https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/introduction/first-steps/first-application)

I have all the necessary jars in my build path.

```
org.restlet.jar
org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.csv.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxb.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.jsonschema.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.smile.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.yaml.jar
```

Whenever I hit the server URL,
I can see the following logs in the server console

```
Jul 08, 2016 12:10:15 AM org.restlet.service.ConverterService toRepresentation
WARNING: Unable to find a converter for this object :    com.shiladitya.restletsample.model.Contact@468bdbc9
Jul 08, 2016 12:10:15 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2016-07-08    00:10:15    127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1   8888    GET /   -   204 0   0   58  http://localhost:8888   Restlet-Framework/2.3.7 -
```

What am I missing here?
If this does not work, I need to look at other options like Spring-Rest.
I thought this is elementary stuff but looks like it is not so.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys for posting this. I found a solution. 
After browsing through stackoverflow, someone mentioned that we should look at the readme files in the lib folder of the restlet distriibution. The readme lists all dependencies of the various restlet extenstions.
I saw a few more dependencies for jackson extension

```
org.restlet.ext.jackson (Restlet Extension - Jackson)
-----------------------
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations_2.4
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.csv_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxb_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.jsonschema_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.smile_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.xml_2.4
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.yaml_2.4
 - org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.13
 - org.codehaus.woodstox.core_4.3
 - org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2api_4.3
```

So, I added jackson-all-1.9.0.jar to my build path.
After that everything works fine as expected.

I hope they improve the restlet documentation.It really sucks!